# Как сделать перенос строки чтобы в данном примере? Чтобы получилось pixel perfect)

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

[image: Необходимо добиться pixel perfect]
Как реализовать pixel perfect в данном случае который в картинке. Как перенести строку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо уменьшить ширину блока, чтобы слово автоматически перенеслось на новую строку, либо использовать тег `<br>` для принудительного переноса: `У меня есть свой проект. Сможем ли мы его доработать / <br>реализовать?`

Comment: Уменьшил ширину заголовка, все получилось, строка перенеслась ))